# How to evaluate this trigonometric integral?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I have to evaluate this integral:
$$\int \frac{\tan^5 x}{\cos^3{x}} dx.$$

I guess I should use substitution, but I don't know what to substitute =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set $\frac 1 {\cos x}=y$, $dy = \frac {\sin x}{\cos^2 x} dx =  \frac {\tan x} {\cos x} dx$.
Also note that $\tan^2 = \frac 1 {\cos^2}-1$. Then your integral becomes 
$$\int \tan^4 x \frac 1 {\cos^2 x} \frac {\tan x}{\cos x} dx =\int  (y-1)^2 y^2 dy .$$

This should be easy to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that$$\frac{\tan^5 x}{\cos^3x}=\frac{\sin^5x}{\cos^8x}=\frac{\sin x(1-\cos^2x)^2}{\cos^8x}.$$So, do the substitution $\cos x=t$ and $\sin x\,\mathrm dx=-\mathrm dt$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Notice that
$$\frac{\tan^5x}{\cos^3x}=\frac{\sin^5x}{\cos^8x}$$
Then if you substitute $t=\cos x$ you get
$$-\frac{\left(1-t^2\right)^2}{t^8}$$
and then just integrate each term.